# Data: Why is a firm stock delisted?

Tags: equities, finance, data, data-source

[Shumway (1997)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2329566) highlights that stock returns in cross-sectional portfolio analysis have to be adjusted for firm delistings.

The CRSP database maintains a monthly delisting file (msedelist) with further information on why a stock is delisted in the field DLSTCD. This field decodes a lot of several delisting reasons (see [here](http://www.crsp.com/products/documentation/delisting-codes)) which are needed for an appropriate adjustment of this stocks return in the delisting month.

Is there an equivalent to CRSPs DLSTCD field on why a stock is delisted available in Thomson Reuters Datastream or any other data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to Thomson Reuters customer zone, log in and look for [GCODE Database](https://customers.reuters.com/a/productsupport/Datascope/GCODES/ric_maint_cds.html). There is a type for delisting, but not very granular.

If you don't have access to customer zone, see user guide, page 137: 
https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/sites/default/files/DSS_11_2_User_Guide.pdf